# Cost for Setup and implementation

Tags: installation, developer, setup

Hi can anyone give me a rough figure please? If I were to pay a developer to set up Civi CRM into Wordpress and just get it up and running, we host it ourselves and maintain it ourselves, but they do the initial setup and train us how to use it? And is there anyone here that can offer that service?
Many thanks

Comment: Where are you based?

Comment: Even a rough figure would need some well documented requirements as otherwise there would be far too much hand-waving involved leaving a lot of uncertainty for both parties.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not possible - for any implementation - to estimate costs in advance. Indeed, this depends on many different facets. Among others, the number of processes you want to implement (contacts, members, participants, payments, etc). Can all processes be supported with standard CiviCRM or is customisation required? Do you already have your data in order or will cleansing it be part of the implementation? Should there be an integration with one or more websites? Does your organisation have enough time available to support during configuration and testing, etc. etc.

Comment: The implementations we (CiviCooP - Netherlands) do have a range between 2,500 and 100,000+ euros. The implementation period can be between 3 months to several years. With the latter, we continuously put parts of a process live during that period. If you want to know a bit more, feel free to get in touch.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider checking out CiviCRM Spark, see https://civicrm.com/ .

It is a hosted version with flat rate pricing. Very reasonable to start with.

One limitation is that there's not a default connection to WordPress. But, if you sign up and like it, there are partners who are Spark migration experts that can help you move to a full featured CiviCRM website using WordPress.